# Is there a way to grep this multiline part from log?

Tags: regex, grep

I have errors in log file like this:

```
[11:16:16 31/10] 2428 ERROR: Wide character in subroutine entry at /home/site/site/app/lib/SC/Contro
ller/Client/Sites.pm line 1584.
Stack:
  [/xxx:1584]
  [/xxx:70]
  [/xxx:133]
```

I want to put this error to some file like:

```
cat apache.error.log | grep "query NS" > apache.error.log-NS
```

But how may I do that for multiline log message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this solution:

```
cat apache.error.log | grep -Pzo '^.*?Wide character.*?\nStack.*?(\n(?=\s).*?)*$'
```

Where `(\n(?=\s).*?)*` means:

- `(...)*` Find multiple times
- `\n` next lines
- `(?=\s)` which starts from whitespace character
- `.*?` until end of that line (notice `$` character at whole regex)

Answer (score 0):

No offense, but I think @Eugen's solution is too generic and since this is a log file it **might be possible** that the reg ex matches unwanted lines too.
So, make sure that we fetch the exact line, This is what i think should be the reg ex. Feel free to comment!

```
^\[\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s\d{2}\/\d{2}\]\s\d+\sERROR\:\sWide\scharacter\sin\ssubroutine\sentry\sat\s[a-zA-Z\/\.]+\s.*?\nStack.*?(\n(?=\s).*?)*$
```

Comment: Not all lines have date. Some lines have date in different format. `\s` is also generic. It is better to get more info than lose some.